# .mxml and .as issue: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: java, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flashdevelop

I have downloaded the source code of the loadtest demo from the Red5 server codebase and trying to set it up in my local. I am using FlashDevelop to setup the Flash Client. During the build phase I realized, this code is written long back, and hence, most of the latest SDKs and jars I am using needs to be replaced by older versions.

I am now able to successfully build the codebase in Eclipse and imported the project as a Flash(AS3) project in FlashDevelop. But, when I am running it in debug mode, I am getting lots of `Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference` errors. When I traced back with the debugger, what I found is, all the objects created in .mxml files, when they are getting used in the .as files, I am getting this error.

I am new to ActionScript/Flex. I did a lot of reading about this error online. What I found is, this happens when an object is getting used before being initialized. But, in this project everything seems to be fine.

So, I am suspecting it can be any kind of version issue of the Flash Player or something else. I am listing here some of the lines that encountered Error#1009:

Error Line 1 (`requestDelay` throwing Error#1009):

function.as: `log('Load delay: '+requestDelay.text);`

loadtest.mxml:

```
<mx:Label text="Request delay" fontWeight="bold"/>
<mx:TextInput id="requestDelay" text="1" width="30" toolTip="For a minimal delay input .1"/>
```

Error Line 2 (`useAMF3` throwing Error#1009):

function.as: `viewer.setEncoding(useAMF3.selected === true ? 3 : 0);`

loadtest.mxml: `<mx:CheckBox label="AMF3" fontWeight="bold" id="useAMF3" x="10" y="40" color="#000000"/>`

During my test I am commenting each line where I am getting this error, and moving ahead. This way I encountered multiple such errors.

If it helps, let me know if I need to provide the `function.as` and `loadtest.mxml` files here. I don't want to clutter the message. Hence, not posting it right now.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Flex manages the creation of object on a per need basis, declaring them in mxml doesn't mean that those object will exist when you'll try to access them in as3 code.

Comment: How can I ensure those declared objects exists when i try to access them in as3 code?

Answer (score 0):

When a component is created it takes soem time until is ready, use the creationComplete event and add a handler to do your work,